# Something is wrong with the return and assigning it to a variable, running the program multiple times in Python

Tags: python, function, variables, return, return-value

How to use `return` during a function?

```
 def planeFun():
     goin=input("should you investigate the plane more, or run away?\n")
     return goin

staying= planeFun()
if staying in ["run", "Run", " run", " Run"]:
    print("blah")
```

For some reason it doesn't work. For some reason, whenever I run my program, the answer to the question, no matter what it is, runs the function all over again, no matter what I enter for the answer to line 2

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: oops, sorry python

Comment: I've copied the code and executed it. It works for me. Its prints blah to the screen. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I have this in a large code, but there is a lot of stuff in-between the function and the answer, and the function is called twice in my larger program, could either of those possibly effect the number of times the function is called?

Comment: From the close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.

Answer (score 0):

It works (as far as I can understand it) in Python IDLE. I run it, type 'run' and 'blah' is printed. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: python3.6.3. like stated above, this is a piece of a larger code, where the function is called twice, and the function and the answer code are separated by other functions, and whatever I answer for the question, runs the function again

Comment: The error is NOT in the function you had provided. Also Python 3 is a language, not an IDE. IDE is the software that helps you debug your code - Pyscripter, IDLE, etc.

Comment: in my larger code, I tried replacing the 'staying' with the actual word result, then when I answered the question and typed run, the entire function ran again, then when I answered again 'run', I got an error that said i have not defined result.